# Set Button Background Color In fragment after button click

Tags: android, fragment, android-tablayout

I have Button In fragment and i have set initial color of button is green and after button click i am sets button color to red but when i am swipe and go another fragment and after come on first fragment the button color sets initial color not red Please help and also after closing my app and restarting the app the color is initial color.

This is my Code For button on click

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.table1:

                btnColor = (ColorDrawable) table1.getBackground();
                colorId = btnColor.getColor();
                if (colorId == getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAcce)) {
                    String value = table1.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TakeOrderActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("myString", value);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    table1.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

            }else
            {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).navigateFragment(1);
            }

            break;
        case R.id.table2:
            btnColor = (ColorDrawable) table2.getBackground();
            colorId = btnColor.getColor();
            if (colorId == getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAcce)){
            String value1 = table2.getText().toString();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), TakeOrderActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("myString", value1);
            startActivity(intent1);
            table2.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            }else
            {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).navigateFragment(1);
            }
            break;
}
```

This is edited code

```
public String getButtonState(int id) {
   SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
   return pref.getString("btn"+id, "not_clicked");
}

public void setButtonState(int id,String state) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("btn"+id, state);
    editor.commit();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if(getButtonState(R.id.table1).equals("clicked")){
        table1.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAcce));
    } else {
        table1.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

    }
    if(getButtonState(R.id.table2).equals("clicked")){
        table2.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAcce));
    } else {
        table2.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    }
    if(getButtonState(R.id.table9).equals("clicked")){
        table9.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    } else {
        table9.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAcce));
    }
    if(getButtonState(R.id.table11).equals("clicked")){
        table11.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    } else {
        table11.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAcce));
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: You have to save the color of your button in the memory somewhere, otherwise Android has no idea weather you changed the button color or not.

Comment: Can i use shared preference for storing the color.

Comment: use saveinstance for saving fragmnet state

Comment: @Dipak yes, SharedPreferences is a good way to do that.

Comment: @Dipak check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to save the state of the button in storage. I recommend you to use SharedPreferences

Simple Workaround for that

1. Store button state in sharedPreference with method `setButtonState(R.id.button1, "clicked")`.
2. Now every time when `onResume()` called of fragment load value form SharedPreferences.

   ```
   public String getButtonState(int id) {
       SharedPreferences pref; = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
       return pref.getString("btn"+id, "not_clicked");
   }

   public void setButtonState(int id,String state) {
       SharedPreferences pref; = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
       Editor editor = pref.edit();
       editor.putString("btn"+id, state);
       editor.commit();
   }
   ```
3. Now write this in onResume() of fragment

   ```
   if(getButtonState(R.id.button1).equals("clicked")){
       //apply clicked button color
   } else {
       //apply another color
   }
   ```

Comment: There are two state as you said. When you click first time on the button then you need to call `setButtonState("clicked")`. Now each time when you onResume you nee to check that button is already clicked or not. If it clicked then you need to apply red color otherwise green.

Comment: you need to pass button_ID as a string into the key. so each button have its unique sharedPreference. I am editing the question

Comment: I have update my code but color is set red to button before button clicked.

Comment: you passing wrong color to table 9 and table 11 button

Comment: Yes, I have also tried But When changed it sets red before buttonclick

Answer (score 0):

When you click on button store the color of Button in SharedPreferences and whenever you come again to that same fragment use that SharedPreferences stored color state to change the color of Button from initial(green) to red.

On click of button:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("AppName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor = editor.putString("BUTTON_COLOR", "Red").commit();
```

Check on UI visibility:

```
if(preferences.getString("BUTTON_COLOR", "").equalsIgnorCase("Red")){
//Set button color to Red
}else{
//Set button color to green
}
```

e.g. Check this in your fragment. As per your code, you are missing to set the state of color when you are clicking on that button. Only trying to get the state of color in onResume, how you will get directly with setting anything.
Check below one to complete.

```
//Variables
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private Editor editor;
private Button btnClickMe;

//In onCreate of fragment
preferences = getSharedPreferences("AppName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = preferences.edit();

//In onCreateView of fragment
btnClickMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClickMe);
btnClickMe.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(preferences.getString("BUTTON_COLOR", "Green").equalsIgnoreCase("Green")){
            btnClickMe.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        }else{
            btnClickMe.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnClickMe:
            if((((ColorDrawable)btnClickMe.getBackground()).getColor()) == getResources().getColor(R.color.red)){
                //navigate to activity
                editor.putString("BUTTON_COLOR", "Green").commit();
                btnClickMe.setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }else{
                //navigate to fragment
                editor.putString("BUTTON_COLOR", "Red").commit();
                btnClickMe.setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please anyone give me the proper solution for change the color of button after fragment is refresh

Comment: But I have many buttons if i am setting up color using above code it display red color before click.

Comment: Here I am using BUTTON_COLOR because I have one button. For you, use BUTTON_1_COLOR, BUTTON_2_COLOR, BUTTON_3_COLOR like this for every button.